# Saving an item that is specific to a user schema but not able to retrieve it back - mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

- I have creared two schemas, user and medicine.
- If a user adds medicines it should show up only in his/her account.
- I am able to save the medicine ids to that specific user but i'm not able to get those medicines back i.e: medicines show for all the other users as well.

---

#### Here's the code snippet that saves meds to specific user:

```
const {userId, medName, medDescription, dose, medType, date, time} = req.body;
  try {
    const newMed = new MedsSchema({
      userId,
      medName,
      medDescription,
      dose,
      medType,
      date,
      time,
    });
    await newMed.save().then(() => res.send({response: 'ok'}));

    const specificUser = await User.findById({_id: userId});
    specificUser.medicines.push(newMed);
    await specificUser.save().then(
      User.findOne(specificUser)
        .populate('medicines')
        .exec(function (err, docs) {
          if (err) return handleError(err);
          console.log(docs);
        }),
    );
```

#### Here's the userSchema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    phone: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true,
    },
    medicines: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'MedsSchema'}],
  },
  {
    toJSON: {
      virtuals: true,
    },
  },
);
```

```
router.get('/getMeds/:Id', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.Id);
  MedsSchema.find({userId: req.params.Id}, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});
```

what do i add to this that will make me get only specific medicines for that specific user instead of getting all medicines?

Comment: Can you show the code where you're trying to find the medicine, because MedsSchema.find({userId: body.userId}) would return the list you want

Comment: added the get request, can you please check now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you edit your first code snippet to

```
const { userId, medName, medDescription, dose, medType, date, time } = req.body;
try {
  const user = await User.findOone({ _id: userId });
  const newMed = await MedsSchema.create({
    userId: user,
    medName,
    medDescription,
    dose,
    medType,
    date,
    time,
  });

  const specificUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: userId }, { $push: { medecines: newMed } });
  return res.json({ newMed, specificUser })
};
```

and in the router

```
router.get('/getMeds/:Id', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.Id);
  const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.params.Id }).populate({ path: 'medicines' })
  console.log(user.medicines)
  return res.json({meds: user.medicines})
});
```

also check the console results to see if everything is working

Comment: The id arrives exactly same as that of the specific user but somehow it is not able to use schema.find


also after editing it shows this error now: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" at path "userId" for model "MedsSchema"

Comment: can you show your medicine schema? you're probably using 'ref' for the userId?

Comment: Yep here it is: userId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},

Comment: Check the edited answer, that should fix it

Comment: Is the error happening in the get route or the create route?

Comment: I checked it is in the getMeds route

Comment: I just edited the answer to use user.medicines instead, check that

Comment: This time it i showing the err for User schema:  CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" at path "_id" for model "User"

Comment: can you show to req.params.Id output because that's what's causing this error?

Comment: when I use MedSchema.find({}) - empty, the id arrives as: 6092a695a9cd5add9fa36a10
whenever i use MedSchema.find({userId: req.params.id}) or your version, that error shows up, also the params at that time arrive as undefined

Comment: No I mean what's the result of console.log(req.params.Id)

Comment: this is the result: 6092a695a9cd5add9fa36a10

Comment: i think what happens is that first time it arrives as undefined and that is where the error is triggered.

Comment: the error is happening because mongoose can't cast the string you're passing to ObjectId. Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters. that's why I'm surprised your Id is not working

Comment: it is crazy i have been at this for two days now and i just can't figure this out, lol!

Comment: try `const user = await User.findOne().populate({ path: 'medicines' })` and `console.log(user.medicines)` see if that returns anything to make sure the issue is related to req.params.id

Comment: if i use user.findOne() the params come as undefined and then an empty array shows up in console.log, if i use medschema.find({}) the params come as the user id.

Comment: Got the issue, so the first time when I reload the nodemon the params come as empty for the first time so that error shows up, after that when i make any change on the frontend side the params arrive as userId and it works just fine, so the problem to fix is how to not let it stop at the first undefined value.